# What results will I see, based on the following routine and diet?

Tags: diet, routine

I'm a 6 ft tall (183cm) male, who weighs 175lbs (80kgs).

I have a very lean build, falling into the "skinny" category.

I've started trying to get in shape a little bit more. I don't really have specific goals, except to just be in better shape. perhaps some more definition, slightly larger biceps and triceps and shoulders.

At the moment, I do the following routine:

- Overhead press, 3 sets of 10 reps, 2 dumbbells at 30lbs each.
- Tricep curls, 3 sets of 10 reps, 1 dumbbell at 30lbs.
- Bicep curls, 3 sets of 10 reps, 1 dumbbell at 30lbs.

I have maybe a 15 minute rest between each type of workout, and a 3 minute rest between each set.

I have started increasing the reps, for example the first sets may be 15, then 12, then 10.

I do this about 4 days a week.

My diet is good....my diet consists of a good balance of carbs and protein, calroic intake is around 2000 - 2500 per day. I'm getting at least 150g of protein each day, although not more than 200.

I'm aware I should probably add squats or some other exercises in, but at the moment I would like to know what results I could expect from the above workout?

Comment: Hi MuyJingo! What is your age? as it is very important to know before advising you on "Weight" increase or "Rep" Increase.

Comment: Hi Bernard, I just turned 28 a few days ago :)

Answer (score 1):

**You won't see much resulting from the listed routine and diet you listed.**

You might see some growth in your triceps, biceps and deltoids. But eventually that will slow and stop if you aren't increasing the weight or difficulty of the exercises. Given that you are already doing 15reps you might not see much more growth at all.

I'd strongly consider looking at other exercises you can do with those, such as rows for your back and single or raised leg squats for your legs just to improve your overall strength. You should also consider adding some cardio, not for the fat-loss that people assume, but for good heart health, i.e. the cardio in cardiovascular.

Comment: If I stick to the same exercises, but increase the weights once my current routine gets "easy" for me, will I see more growth or strength? I plan to join a gym in a few months, which is when I will start a more complete workout.

Comment: If you do the same exercises, but increase the weight you will see both growth and strength increases for that movement. Eventually this too will subside, but if you can keep increasing the weight you will keep seeing improvements - for those movements and muscles only.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I have a few more questions if you don't mind. What would be the difference between increasing weights and increasing weights? Should I increase when it gets easy or at a fixed time? Do the rests between sets matter?

Comment: Can't answer the first typo, haha. I personally increase weight when it gets to easy, but there are a multitude of routines, the last is too complex a question for a comment.

Comment: OK thanks :). I meant to ask about increasing weights vs increasing reps and keeping the same weight.